# SQL Server query is needed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables one for `users` and other for `projects`.

`users` and `projects` are linked with `userid` and `projectid`

Projects are different project types ranging from 1 to 100

My question is I need a query to find whether the user is having three project types 19,20,21

My script is returning all user who are assigned to projects as `19,20,21`, but I need to find out whether a user has all these three projects

For a user 21 is base project and if for that user 19 and 20 projects exist need to pick latest project creation date out of 19 and 20

Need help in this regard

Comment: You should do two things to help improve your question: show the schema of these two tables, and post the query you have been working on.

Comment: can you give sample records? with your desired result?

Comment: What sql server flavor are you using 2005/2008/etc?

Answer (score 2):

For selecting the latest date you can do a query like:

```
DECLARE @LatestDate DATETIME

SELECT @LatestDate = MAX(Dates) -- your column with the date stored.
FROM project -- I would guess your dates are stored here
WHERE projectid IN (19, 20)
```

But in lack of information is hard to write the correct answer